# Core Data migration not persisting new attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I'm performing a Core Data lightweight migration, adding a new attribute to an existing object. For the sake of example, say I've got Songs and Playlists, where there's a many-to-many relationship between the two (i.e., songs can be in multiple playlists, and playlists contain multiple songs).

I added a new Core Data model version, and then added a new Playlist attribute called `songCount`. I added the property to my model class manually, and then overrode the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors for adding a new `Song` to a `Playlist` like so:

```
@dynamic songCount;

- (void)addSongObject:(Song *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"songs"
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                   usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveSongs] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"songs"
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                  usingObjects:changedObjects];

    // don't think the broadcasts are necessary when using the setter
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"songCount"];
    self.songCount = @([[self primitiveSongs] count]);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"songCount"];
}
```

This all works correctly. When I add a song to a playlist and then do a Core Data fetch against the playlist, the playlist has the correct value for `songCount` (I can even have the fetch sort by song count, which was the whole point).

However, when I restart the app, the `songCount` attribute for all my Playlists is `nil`. What did I miss? I did a `[context save]` and the playlist does contain the new song, it just didn't save the song count. It's not a transient attribute, and the persistentStoreCoordinator doesn't complain about the migration. I'm not sure what else could be going wrong, or where to look for debugging.

Comment: Try not overriding the generated accessor and adding the songCount manually. If it persists, your override is faulty. `[playlist addSongObject:song]; playlist.songCount = @(playlist.songCount.integerValue +1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by logging the managed object context associated with the Song and the Playlist. They were different, so `[context save]` was saving the new Song but not the Playlist it was added to. Core Data fixed the consistency issue for me automatically, by adding the Song to the Playlist's inverse relationship, but it didn't update the `songCount` automatically. Don't ask me why I had two different managed object contexts in my app.